# Transaction tracking Here maps

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

Is there any way that you can access project information (mainly number of Transactions) in Here Maps API? The only way I was able to get that is through browser with logging.

What i need is access from code (REST, library or anything similar).
I can provide APP_ID and APP_CODE but not account login information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No there is not. Only way is to connect to web page developer.here.com with your credentials